# How to authenticate Laravel users to wordpress user using same password

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-5

We converted a Laravel website (4.2) to Wordpress (4.9.7).

We need to use same password which is using in Laravel. But when we are login in Wordpress using same password it shows wrong password. Can you please advise how to authenticate Laravel user password to Wordpress users.

Comment: How did you "convert"?

Comment: We just copy and paste laraval Hash password string to Wordpress password field.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses bcrypt to secure store passwords.
Wordpress uses MD5.
You can try by using this plugin that says to change the password encryption of wordpress:

https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/password-bcrypt/

Unfortunately it is not tested with the last 3 version of wordpress... but it could work.

**EDIT**
there is another plugin you can try:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-bcrypt/

**EDIT 2**

here you can find all the plugin tagged with bcrypt

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/bcrypt/

Comment: there is a plugin named [Force Strong Hashing](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-strong-hashing-littlebizzy/) that is tested on last wordpress version...